# Angular(11.2.14) ng-select2 error during ng-serve

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install, angular-ngselect

facing this error while trying ng-serve in a freshly cloned repo works fine in my previous device (new device , coworker suspect M1 apple silicon is what caused this error)

full error log https://pastebin.com/va40cDXs

```
Error: node_modules/ng-select2/lib/ng-select2.component.d.ts:35:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/Users/name/Documents/Angular/project/project_fe/project-fe/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

35     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<NgSelect2Component, never>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/ng-select2/lib/ng-select2.component.d.ts:36:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/Users/name/Documents/Angular/project/project_fe/project-fe/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration'.

36     static ɵcmp: i0.ɵɵComponentDeclaration<NgSelect2Component, "ng-select2", never, { "data": "data"; "placeholder": "placeholder"; "dropdownParent": "dropdownParent"; "allowClear": "allowClear"; "value": "value"; "width": "width"; "disabled": "disabled"; "options": "options"; }, { "valueChanged": "valueChanged"; }, never, ["option, optgroup"]>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/ng-select2/lib/ng-select2.module.d.ts:5:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/Users/name/Documents/Angular/project/project_fe/project-fe/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

5     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<NgSelect2Module, never>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
m

Error: node_modules/ng-select2/lib/ng-select2.module.d.ts:6:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/Users/name/Documents/Angular/project/project_fe/project-fe/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration'.

6     static ɵmod: i0.ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration<NgSelect2Module, [typeof i1.NgSelect2Component], [typeof i2.CommonModule], [typeof i1.NgSelect2Component]>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/ng-select2/lib/ng-select2.module.d.ts:7:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/Users/name/Documents/Angular/project/project_fe/project-fe/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectorDeclaration'.

7     static ɵinj: i0.ɵɵInjectorDeclaration<NgSelect2Module>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: ./node_modules/ng-select2/fesm2015/ng-select2.mjs 286:12-17
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
```

upon npm install here's the log

```
npm WARN @zxing/ngx-scanner@3.3.0 requires a peer of @zxing/browser@^0.0.10 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng-select2@1.3.1 requires a peer of @angular/common@^13.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng-select2@1.3.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@^13.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng-select2@1.3.1 requires a peer of @types/select2@^4.0.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng-select2@1.3.1 requires a peer of jquery@3.5.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-barcode@0.3.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-barcode@0.3.0 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-barcode@0.3.0 requires a peer of zone.js@^0.8.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.7.0 requires a peer of jasmine-core@>=3.8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

Answer (score 0):

changing ng-select2 in package.json solve my problem
from
`"ng-select2": "^1.2.2",`
to
`"ng-select2": "1.2.5",`

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete the node modules
2. install npm (npm i)
3. Then start the server (ng s )

Its will works

Answer (score -1):

try `npm i` first then try `ng serve`